# Rails: load helper_method methods inside Rack application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rack

I have some helper methods defined in my `ApplicationController`. For performance issues, I have a Rack app for a `/search` route, and I need to use some of these methods in this Rack. I can't move them to a library or something right now.

A short example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   helper_method :user_participants
   ...
end
```

And on Rack:

```
class SearchRack
   def self.call(env)
     # need to call user_participants here
   end
end
```

What can I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to move them to out a module and then include that module inside the Rack application and inside the `ApplicationController` as well. I cannot think of another way to do it, and this is the cleanest.